# Footer background should extend to bottom of browser

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with fixing the footer to the bottom of the browser .. The problem is when resolution changes or windows resizes the footer content overlaps the content of the website, here is the current css for footer div

```
div.footer {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
    }
```

Does anybody knows how can I fix this? Thank you

**UPDATE:**

This is what I need exactly but for some reason it doesn't work for my web page, it does work when I cut paste code to the blank page, but since my page is full with content and everything, what are the important elements to include?  [Here](http://www.lwis.net/profile/CSS/sticky-footer.html)is the url.

The above trick works only if my website has filled content if I have some lets say few lines the above trick doesn't work.

**UPDATE II**

My website has dynamic content so I think can't use this sort of CSS Sticky footers because sometimes the website will just have few lines sometimes be packed with content. Thats why the footer is not sticking to the bottom of the webpage.. its not problem to stick the footer if there is plenty content on the website the problem is without.

Comment: So you're using/testing with IE? Is the doctype strict?

Comment: yes IE7 included as well as ff and IE8 , problem only happens in IE7

Comment: This is one of those things that can be solved cross browser, right down to Netscape 4, in eight lines using a table. It's 2010 now, and still there is no reliable, cross-browser, pure CSS way of achieving the same thing easily, and without people having to put up bounties on SO to find a solution. It' a shame, is what it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you have here is a common problem for which there is no common answer, but what I would try if I were you since all these above suggestions apparently aren't working, I'd try to set my page container background to any color let say white (#FFFFFF) and I'd set background color of body to any other then white let say grey (#CCCCCC). And finaly set footer position to relative and of course it must be placed after everything if you want it alway to be at the bottom. This way you'll get what you need 100 % sure if you follow step by step instructions.

Comment: what is "page container background" and how is it different from "background color of body" (`<body style="background-color:#CCC;">`)?

Comment: Only problem is when i have a table within this body, that has two many columns to show. (making IE horizontally scrollable). In that case, as you scroll to the right, you will see that the background changes to #CCCCCC

Comment: in continuation to above comment, i solved the issue by doing a small jquery --  $(document).ready(function() {
                if ($('body table').width() > 1000)
                    $('body').width($('body table').width() + 300); 
            }); --------- basically adding 300 to table's width and make that as body's width

Answer (score 8):

Checkout [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) for an excellent cross-browser compatible method.

What that site essentially does is make the footer stick BENEATH the browser edge, and gives it a negative margin that has the same value as the footer's height. This way, the footer is sure to stick to the bottom.

Comment: Looked promising until I tested it in most recent version of IE8. Doesn't work. To my surprise. Also see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900813/footer-background-should-extend-to-bottom-of-browser/1901381#1901381

Answer (score 3):

You can add a *push div* to the last element before the footer in order to always assure that the footer doesn't overlap the content.

Given this example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="header" />
    <div class="content" />
    <div class="footer_push" />
    <div class="footer" />
  </body>
</html>
```

If `<div class="footer" />` is always `75px` high, use the following CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; } /* Take all available vertical space */

/* Push the bottom of the page 75px.
   This will not make scrollbars appear
   if the content fits already. */
.footer_push { height: 75px; }

/* Position the footer */
.footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; height: 75px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to give the footer a fixed `height` and to *push* the footer with another div of the same height to the bottom. There's however more browser specific stuff which you need to take into account:

1. The `html` and `body` must besides having a height of 100% **no** (default) margin to avoid the footer being pushed further to below that amount of margin.
2. The `p` and `div` elements throughout the page must have **no** `margin-top` to avoid the footer being pushed further to below that amount of top-margins in under each Firefox.
3. The "container" `div` must use **`min-`**`height` of `100%` instead of `height` to avoid the footer to overlap the remaining of the content. IE6 which doesn't know `min-height` just works fine with `height`, so you'll need to add a `* html` hack for this.

All with all, here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), just copy'n'paste'n'run it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
        <title>SO question 1900813</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }
            p, div {
                margin-top: 0; /* Fix margin collapsing behaviour in FF. Use padding-top if necessary. */
            }
            #container {
                position: relative;
                min-height: 100%;
            }
            * html #container {
                height: 100%; /* This is actually "min-height" for IE6 and older. */
            }
            #pushfooter {
                height: 50px; /* Must be the same as footer height. */
            }
            #footer {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                height: 50px;
            }      
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <p>Some content</p>
            <div id="pushfooter"></div>
            <div id="footer">Footer</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**: after more testing I realized that this indeed does **not** work in IE8 (I still consider it as a beta so I didn't really use/test it, sorry about that), *unless* you let it render in IE7 compatibility modus (insert sad smilie here) by adding the following meta tag to the `<head>` (which I already added to the SSCCE here above):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

*or* to let it render in quirks mode by using a "wrong" doctype (either remove the `<!doctype>` or pick one of the doctypes associated with painfully red `Q` boxes in IE [here](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/)). But I wouldn't do that, that has more negative side-effects as well.

And, surprisingly, the http://www.cssstickyfooter.com site as someone else here mentioned here which used an entirely different approach also did **not** work in IE8 here (try to resize browser window in y-axis, the footer won't move along it as opposed to other browsers, including IE6/7). That browser keeps astonishing me. Really.

Comment: This works but my footer is still not on the bottom it is somewhere in the middle .. not really sticked to the bottom

Comment: Then the problem lies somewhere else than in the information you provided as far. Did you for instance copy'n'paste'n'run the above snippet **unchanged**? If it still fails, please tell the browser details.

Comment: I've also updated my answer before you updated the question. Did you read it? The **Edit** part below the code example. In the future, please test in as many browsers as possible. Your site works fine in IE6/7, FF, Safari, Chrome, Opera, but indeed not in IE8. You need to add a `meta` header as I outlined in my updated answer and the updated SSCCE. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the footers Position to relative and playing around with a negative top margin to get it how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a Sticky Footer, you can find a lot of resources like this one: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do. I you want it to be always visible on the bottom of your screen, you should use

```
div.footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Be sure to get some padding on the bottom of your body (or container, so that people can actually scroll to the bottom of the text). The main problem here is that when resizing everything it will overlap.

If you just want to have a footer that has a background-image / colour that stretches all the way till the end (for pages that are not fullpage height) you could try to use a faux column principle or even try to give your body the background colour of your footer and fix the header / content background.

Today I stumbled across this page:
http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html

Could be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#wpr{
    display: table;
    height:  100%;
    width:   100%;
}
.dsp-tr{
    display: table-row;
}
.dsp-tc{
    display: table-cell;
}
#ftr-cnr{
    text-align:     center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#ftr{
    background-color: red;
    padding:          10px 0px;
    font-size:        24px;
}


<div id="wpr">
  <div class="dsp-tr">
    <div class="dsp-tc">
      body
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dsp-tr">
    <div class="dsp-tc" id="ftr-cnr">
      <div id="ftr">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

display: table does not make it a table, a `<div>` is still a `<div>`, it just tells the browser to display it as table.
i tested it in chrome and firefox
let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem a few times. We could not find any cross browser CSS only solution. We finally resorted to JQuery. We wrote our own (i can't publish) but this one http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_139/article_244-jquery-sticky-footer.htm looks promising:

```
$(function(){
    positionFooter(); 
    function positionFooter(){
        if($(document.body).height() < $(window).height()){
            $("#pageFooterOuter").css({position: "absolute",top:($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-$("#pageFooterOuter").height())+"px"})
        }   
    }

    $(window)
        .scroll(positionFooter)
        .resize(positionFooter)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a **DOCTYPE** declaration in the top of your HTML?

If so, there is a good chance I have a solution for you.

I was trying to do a height:100% table or div (assuming this is a basic cornerstone to the expanding footer feature)

No matter what I did, the 100% height didn't work! the elements just didn't stretch...

I narrowed it down to a very basic HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border: 2px solid red; height: 100%">Hello
World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but the DIV didn't stretch all the way down (the 100% was ignored). This was true also for tables with plain height="100%" attribute.

As a desperate last result guess, I removed the DOCTYPE row, resulting in this code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border: 2px solid red; height: 100%">Hello
World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it worked!

I'm sure there is a good explanation, but I really didn't care since it solved the problem

**Update**

See related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997842/why-certain-doctype-declarations-cause-100-height-tables-and-divs-to-stop-workin) (asked by me)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a fairly simple solution that doesn't use any CSS height hacks or any of that.

You just set your `<body>` with the background you want the footer to have, and then put everything besides the footer in a `<div>` with the properties you would normally give to the body tag.

This gets the footer to "extend" its color to the bottom of the page when there is short dynamic content without expanding it needlessly when there is a lot of dynamic content. The "virtual body" div can still have a gradient followed by a solid color, and the footer's background is hiding in the body tag, only showing up on short pages. (Works great if you need a solid color to continue after your footer gradient ends, or if you just need the background to match the footer color)

CSS

```
body    {background-color: #000; }
#primary_container { background: #FFF url('/images/bgvert.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x; }
#footer { background: #000; }
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="primary_container">
    <!-- most content, can be short or long -->
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <!-- if primary content + footer is less than browser height, body background color
       displays below this. If it is more, you get normal scroll behavior to the end
       of footer and body background color is never seen -->
  </div>
</body>
```