# Why certain DOCTYPE declarations cause 100%-height tables and divs to stop working?

Tags: html, doctype, quirks-mode, transitional

It seems to me that some `DOCTYPE` declarations in IE (6-8) may cause the browser to ignore `height="100%"` on tables and divs (`style="height:100%"`)

E.g

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Test1</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="border: 2px solid red; height: 100%">
  Hello World
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Will render the `DIV` with the height of the text, it will not stretch. Removing the `DOCTYPE` declaration causes the `DIV` to stretch vertically as desired.

So my questions are:

1. Why does it happen?
2. How do you keep the `DOCTYPE` and *still* allow tables to stretch?
3. Does / did it happen to you?
4. Did you know about it?, is it well known?

Comment: There's a specific reason why `height: 100%` works without a DOCTYPE. See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Because ancient browsers had odd, inconsistent behavior and browsers treat Doctypes like [an intelligence test](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) to see if the author is writing code to the standards or to what they learned from W3Schools a decade ago. If you have `height: 100%` and the height of the parent element is `auto` then [`100%` means `auto`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property).
2. Generally, you don't. It screams "[layout table](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)". That said, set heights or minimum heights on the html and body elements. There are other techniques, but I don't have a handy link at the moment as, oddly, I've never been in a position where I needed the technique.
3. It is what browsers are supposed to do, so …
4. Well, I am answering this question …

Comment: So removing the DOCTYPE declaration is pure evil? And having footers that stick to the bottom is bad UI?

Comment: Yes, and no. You might be misinterpreting my comment about having the bottom of a **table** sticking to the bottom of the window and/or page (whichever is longer).

Comment: So to understand, sticking to the bottom, is not the problem, but rather the "layout table" pattern because a) it can't be done using it (if you keep the DOCTYPE) and b) also a bad practice (http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/). To do so one should use other techniques (e.g. DIVs and CSS purely). did I get it right?

Comment: You should use whatever markup has the semantics that best describes the content (div being the last resort, as it has no semantics, and tables only being an option if the data is tabular) with CSS.

Answer (score 9):

A real solution to this "problem" would be using the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
}

#mydiv {
    height: 100%;
}
```

However remember that a border adds height.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the doctype the browser goes into quirks mode which does things differently to help older code that is not validated to render correctly.

You have to set the height on the container element so the div with 100% height doesn't inherit height: auto;

You could try a switching from transitional to strict but I doubt this will fix your issue.