# Relative dimentions in different doc types

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was messing around with a layout and never added a doc type to my file.  After adding a doc type:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

My content div that had `height:100%` was overflowing the page instead of growing to the size of the browser window.  To get the functionality to before adding a doc type I had to add this java script.

```
wHeight = $(window).height();
$('#content').height(wHeight);
```

Why did the doc type affect the layout in this way and can I fix this without using java script?

Comment: Can you give more code? At least the code for your content div (for #content)?

Comment: The answer to your questions could be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997842/why-certain-doctype-declarations-cause-100-height-tables-and-divs-to-stop-worki

Comment: Make sure its parent element specifies a `height` explicitly like `height: 500px` so `100%` is not ambiguous. Anytime you use percentages to size an element, ask your self, "100% of what?"

Comment: Why does the doc type matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As darksky mentioned, your div has to be contained in another one for the % to take effect. HTML is pretty much just a bunch of containers stacked inside each other. First we have the  container, then the  container inside of that, and finally the  container. Ifg you tell your container to be 100%, it doesn't know a 100% of what, so the right way is something in the lines of:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, but why does the doc type matter?

Comment: According to this page: http://able2know.org/topic/39084-1 , the "height" table tag was depreciated in HTML 4.01, so using any doctype with that or beyond shouldn't let it work.


URL: http://able2know.org/topic/39084-1